# How to get Content-type using html simple dom?

Tags: php, content-type, simple-html-dom

I tried `find('meta[http-equiv="Content-type"]')` but it failed to retrieve that information.

Comment: "simple dom" means simplehtmldom as in simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleHTMLDom doesn't use quoted string literals in the selector. It's just `elem[attr=value]`. And the comparison of *value* seems to be case-sensitive (there may be a way to make it case-insensitive, but that I don't know)*

E.g.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
// most likely one one element but foreach doesn't hurt
foreach( $html->find('meta[http-equiv=content-type]') as $ct ) { 
  echo $ct->content, "\n";
}
```

prints `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`.

*edit: yes, there is a way to perform a case-insensitive match, use `*=` instead of `=`

```
find('meta[http-equiv*=content-type]')
```

edit2: btw that `http-equiv*=content-type` thingy would also match `<meta http-equiv="haha-no-content-types"...` (it only tests if the string is somewhere in the attribute's value). But it's the only case-insensitive function/operator I could find. I guess you can live with it in this case ;-)
edit 3: It uses preg_match('.../i') and the pattern/selector is directly passed to that function. Therefore you *could* do something like `http-equiv*=^content-type$` to match `http-equiv="Content-type"` but not `http-equiv="xyzContent-typeabc"`. But I don't know if this is a warranted feature.

Comment: Thanks,I'll live happily with it!

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type is typically part of the http-response headers - not in the body. Where did you get the xml document from?

Answer (score 0):

I would go `foreach` on `$this->find('meta');` in case of differently written `content-type` - I think that browsers aren't in this case case sensitive, while php might be.